# Could not proceed while implementing map_view

Tags: flutter, dart, sdk, android-mapview

I'm trying to implement map_view inside my flutter app, but when i provides the dependencies and then run the app, its shows some error. And, i don't know how to fix it.

My error:-
* Error running Gradle:
ProcessException: Process "D:\development\flutter\flutter_course\android\gradlew.bat" exited abnormally:

> Configure project :map_view
>   WARNING: The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (27.0.3) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (28.0.3) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.2.1.
>   Android SDK Build Tools 28.0.3 will be used.
>   To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'" from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a default version of the build tools.
>            *********************************************************
>   WARNING: This version of shared_preferences will break your Android build if it or its dependencies aren't compatible with AndroidX.
>            This warning prints for all Android build failures. The real root cause of the error may be unrelated.
>            *********************************************************

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.2.51 and higher. Project 'android' is using version 1.1.2-4.

My build.gradle:-

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.1.2-4'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

My pubspec.yaml file:-

```
name: flutter_course
description: A new Flutter project.

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  scoped_model: ^1.0.1
  http: ^0.12.0+2
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.3+1
  rxdart: ^0.22.0
  map_view: ^0.0.14

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter


# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
   - assets/race.jpg
   - assets/bg.jpg
  #  - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.io/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.io/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  fonts:
    - family: Oswald
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/Oswald-Bold.ttf
          weight: 700
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.io/custom-fonts/#from-packages
analyzer:
  strong-mode: true
  language:
    enableSuperMixins: true
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your kotlin version to 1.2.51

```
  classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.2.51
```

And check targetSdkVersion inside app-->buildGradle, If it's below 28 change it to 28

Let me know if there is a problem

Comment: I already tried it, there's no change, its showing the same error.